# Hot-reload (HMR) with 'bun dev'

Tags: typescript, hot-reload, bun, hono

I'm trying the new [bun](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun) platform (v0.1.6) with [Hono](https://honojs.dev/docs/getting-started/bun/).

The steps I've followed:

```bash
bun create hono test-api
cd test-api
bun dev
```

Then the server shows this message:

```
$ bun dev
[1.00ms] bun!! v0.1.6


  Link: http://localhost:3000
```

When I modify any file, the server detects it and then reload the application BUT I have no idea how to invoke my application REST API.

If I execute: `curl localhost:3000` the response is a transpiled JS code:

```
import {
__require
} from "http://localhost:3000/bun:wrap";
import {
__HMRClient as Bun
} from "http://localhost:3000/bun:wrap";
Bun.activate(false);
import {
__HMRModule as HMR
} from "http://localhost:3000/bun:wrap";
import * as $9121e9 from "http://localhost:3000/node_modules/hono/dist/index.js";
var { Hono} = __require($9121e9);
var hmr = new HMR(2320229645, "src/index.ts"), exports = hmr.exports;
(hmr._load = function() {
  const app = new Hono;
  const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3000;
  const home = app.get("/", (c) => {
    return c.json({ message: "Hello World!" });
  });
  console.log(`Running at http://localhost:${port}`);
  var src_default = {
    port,
    fetch: home.fetch
  };
  hmr.exportAll({
    default: () => src_default
  });
})();
var $$hmr_default = hmr.exports.default;
hmr._update = function(exports) {
  $$hmr_default = exports.default;
};

export {
  $$hmr_default as default
};

//# sourceMappingURL=http://localhost:3000/.map
```

The original generated code in `index.ts` is:

```js
import { Hono } from "hono";

const app = new Hono();

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3000;

const home = app.get("/", (c) => {
  return c.json({ message: "Hello World!" });
});

console.log(`Running at http://localhost:${port}`);

export default {
  port,
  fetch: home.fetch,
};
```

I didn't find doc about `bun dev` in the [bun README.md](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/blob/main/README.md) but when the application is created It appears a message to execute "bun dev" without anything else, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

How can I invoke the hono API Hello-Word running `bun dev`?

On the other hand, if I execute: `bun src/index.ts` the application works as expected but without hot reloading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With version v0.2.0 bun has enabled hot reloading of code in Bun's JavaScript runtime. This is a very experimental feature available from Bun v0.2.0. [Official Doc for --hot](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun#bun---hot). For above code you may use:

```
 bun --hot src/index.ts
```

OR

```
 bun run --hot src/index.ts
```

Comment: the important thing to note is, the ORDER MATTERS. `bun run --hot server.js` works, but `bun run server.js --hot` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

**For current version (from 0.2.0) see accepted answer.**

In the current version (v 0.1.6) the command `bun dev` is only for front-end projects, not for back-end (REST APIs...). According to a bun committer answer in [Bun Discord server](https://discord.com/channels/876711213126520882/887787428973281300/1005043151569965056)

However, we can achieve a similar result using [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) tool:

```bash
bun add -d nodemon
```

Add the file `nodemon.json` to your project root with the following content:

```json
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": ".ts,.js",
  "ignore": [],
  "exec": "bun ./src/index.ts"
}
```

Then, execute your project with this command:

```bash
bun run nodemon
```

[image: nodemon output]

When you change your source files, the command will restart the `bun` interpreter automatically